# Do changelings have their own gods?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

Jem'Hadar and Vorta see the Changelings as gods. I'm not sure if Changelings are deluded enough to actually believe this, or if they just appreciate the attention.

However, is there anything in the canon (or non-canon) which states whether changelings themselves have gods? Or are at least open to gods existing?

Comment: My gut instinct says no. Like most [false gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goa%27uld#As_false_gods_and_opposition), they've probably gone beyond the primitive superstitions of their followers.

Comment: “I'm not sure if changelings are deluded enough to actually believe this, or if they just appreciate the attention.” — I can’t remember the reference, but I think the Founders (“changelings” is kind of a racist term bro) intentionally engineered/raised the Jem’Hadar and the Vorta to think of them as gods. They did create both species (give or take), so from a certain perspective, they *are* gods to them.

Comment: In non-canon works (the ds9 novels) the changelings have a "creator" they look to/for almost as a god.

Comment: @TZHX Sounds like an answer to me, if you can come up with a citation or two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### In secondary canon (DS9 novels), yes.

From [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Changeling) (emphasis mine):

> The origin of the Changeling was unknown though according to the Female Changeling they were once a monoform based species until they evolved. According to the elderly Changeling Indurane, **their race begun with a semi mythical being called the Progenitor which created the universe and everything in it** according to their beliefs. This entity was noted to have taken a population of "solids" and imbued them with its own malleable characteristics which led to the creation of the Great Link. After which, the creature departed known space leaving the Changeling incapable of reproducing though with lengthy life spans.

This is sourced to the DS9 novels *The Dominion: Olympus Descending* and  *Warpath*.